# Determine how many times my Raspberry Pi has rebooted

Tags: bash, reboot, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi in bash script and I wanted to know if it was possible to determine how many times the RPi rebooted. The point is that my program is doing something and if I reach 3 reboots it starts doing something else.

I already found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131888/is-there-a-way-to-tell-how-many-times-my-computer-has-rebooted-in-a-24-hour-peri
but the problem is that it gives me a number that can't be modified easily.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Errrr.... "a number that can't be modified easily"? I don't get your meaning there. You get the number of reboots, why would you want to *modify* it? (And why do you think you cannot?) Please clarify why the linked answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry, not clear, but what I wanted to say is that I want my variable to be null at the beginning of the program and increase according to the number of reboots. With the program I found, the command already gives me a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.

```
last reboot | grep ^reboot | wc -l
```

That's the number of reboots your system did. Since your program will not "survive" a reboot, I assume that you want the number of reboots *since your program ran the first time*. So you want to store the number of reboots the first time around, and read it back on (the first and) subsequent starts:

```
if [[ ! -e ~/.reboots ]]
then
    echo $(last reboot | grep ^reboot | wc -l) > ~/.reboots
fi

INITIAL_REBOOTS=$(cat ~/.reboots)

# Now you can check if the *current* number of reboots
# is larger than the *initial* number by three or more:

REBOOTS=$(last reboot | grep ^reboot | wc -l)
if [[ $(expr $REBOOTS - $INITIAL_REBOOTS) -ge 3 ]]
then
    echo "Three or more reboots"
else
    echo "Less than three reboots"
fi
```

The above lacks all kinds of finesse and error checking (e.g. in case someone has tampered with `~/.reboots`), but is meant as proof of concept only.

Comment: Thank you. I tested it but when I ran it after a reboot it still gives me 0 (73-73 then after reboot 74-74). Your code substracts two identical numbers.

Comment: @K.Wa: That's because I wrote the first version before thinking about a program not surviving a reboot. (That's what you get for whipping out these answers during compiler breaks without really thinking about them. ;-) ) Check updated answer.

Comment: Again thank you. Do I have to create .reboots because it doesn't exist on my RPi ?

Comment: @K.Wa: If you look again, the first part of the script *creates* the file to store the initial number of reboots. If you create that file manually, you defeat that purpose. To the contrary, you have to *delete* the file to reset the reboot count.

Comment: This is what I thought but when I run it I have an error telling me : No such file or directory

Comment: @K.Wa: Check spelling, and permissions. (Worked here, copy & paste.)

Comment: The problem was coming from the [[ ]], I replaced them by [ ]. Thank you very much.

Comment: @K.Wa: Then you are using some other shell, not bash as indicated by the tag. (`[[]]` is a bash-ism)